# Web Design - Tables vs css learning web design

Tags: css, web

I am currently taking an intro to web design class. We are learning to mock up our sites in photoshop then build the sites in dreamweaver using tables.

As I have been looking on the internet about web design I have been seeing pages about responsive web design and using css instead of tables.

I see that responsive web design may be something that is too complicated for beginners.

But what about using css instead of tables? is one better than the other? and is tables an older, possibly outdated way of doing web design?

Comment: You're learning great techniques for 1999. For something this millennium, you may want to question the methods being taught. Complicated or not, any instructor should be teaching you current methods. Tables for layout are a non-starter. And even full site Photoshop mock-ups are not nearly as frequent as they were 10 years ago.

Comment: It depends on the task, sometimes tables are non avoidable. For grids, data representation etc. However, you should not design your website on tables. Use a div layout with CSS. Only use tables unless absolutely necessary. Also, you can use CSS with tables as well ;)

Comment: You are actually taught by a wrong person, tables are not the right thing to design the websites with.

Comment: css is the main language design. It is not difficult to learn.  [w3schools/css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_intro.asp)

Comment: Tables is still the way to go when displaying Tabular data, after all that is its purpose. However designing using CSS would offer more flexibility. Although I wouldn't recommend using Dreamweaver as they tend to have bloated code.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are still good for tabular data, but not for positioning graphical elements. If you're looking for a tool to quickly generate you some code from a PSD, try [converxy.com](http://converxy.com).

Responsive web design does take some getting used to, but I wouldn't say that it's technically difficult. Try hard things, it'll make you stronger.

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard (from all the websites/blogs that I've read up on) that you should only use tables for data you want to turn into a table and nothing else. Well, actually, HTML emails use tables as well. But other than that, just use CSS!

It might be tough to learn in the beginning, but give it some time for your mind to understand it, and you'll be fine. It's not too hard once it clicks.